# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in extjs4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working in extjs4 MVC, where I have a problem when I am storing data using a local storage, and I am going to change the proxy type dynamically from ajax to localStorage.

After setting the data to localstorage I got a error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

My model:

```
Ext.define('Am.model.sn.UserModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    //idproperty:'userId',//fields property first position pk. 
        fields: ['userId','firstName','middleName','lastName','languageId','primaryEmail','birthDate','password','securityQuestionId','securityQuestionAnswer','isMale','creationTime','ipAddress','confirmationCode','userStatusId']

});
```

My controller:

```
Ext.define('Am.controller.sn.UserController1',
{
    init:function()
    {
        console.log('Initialized Users! This happens before the Application launch function is called'); 
        this.control(
        {
            ...
        });
    },

    remeberMe : function()
    {
        console.log("check box selected");
        var email=this.getUserName().getValue();
        var password=this.getPassword().getValue();
        console.log("email="+email);
        var objCheckBox=Ext.getCmp('checkbox');
        if(objCheckBox.getValue()==true)

        {
            window.localStorage.clear();

            // Here I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
            var lsProxy = new Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage({
                id: 'localp',
                type:'localstorage',                
            });

            var modelObject = Ext.ModelManager.create(
            {
                primaryEmail:email,
                password: password,
                proxy:lsProxy
            }, 'Balaee.model.sn.UserModel');

            modelObject.setProxy(lsProxy);
            modelObject.save();
        } else {
            console.log("check box is not selected");
        } 
    },
});
```

Please give me suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

First off, if I understand your code correctly - you are loading the users and their passwords to the client side. This is a massive security risk as anyone can see this data (with a few mouse clicks).

Second, `LocalStorage` doesn't have a `type` config.

Third, if you are really getting the error on this line (and not some sub line in the call stack):

```
var lsProxy = new Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage({
```

Than it can only be that the `Ext.data.proxy` is not in scope.

Try to add to your controller this config:

```
requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
```

Let us know what happens.